# Subtracting or adding vectors in a matrix

Tags: arrays, fortran

I am trying to subtract vectors of a matrix. In other words suppose that I have matrix `A` with elements

```
x1    x2    x3    x4
y1    y2    y3    y4
z1    z2    z3    z4
```

I want to be able to subtract vectors

```
x1  
y1
z1
```

and

```
x2
y2
z2
```

How would I be able to do this? I tried doing

```
implict none
real, dimension(3,4) :: A
real,dimension(3) :: vector
vector(1)=A(1,1)-A(1,2)
vector(2)=A(2,1)-A(2,2)
vector(3)=A(3,1)-A(3,2)
```

However, this is rather crude. Also, this method would be impractical if I need to compute several sums or residues, especially when the matrix is very large. I want to be able to do it more elegantly.

Is there a way to specify a vector inside a matrix? Or is there a roundabout way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can specify array slices by `[start]:[end][:stride]` (Fortran 2008 Standard, Cl. 6.5.3 "Array elements and array sections": R621). To select all elements along a specified dimension, choose e.g., `A(:,1)`. Your difference then reads:

```
implicit none
real, dimension(3,4) :: A
real,dimension(3) :: vector
vector(:)=A(:,1)-A(:,2)
```

or even

```
vector=A(:,1)-A(:,2)
```